# jquery Change input mask template based on value length

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, user-interface, input

I cannot figure out how to change the input template mask based on value length. 
For example: I have two car number templates '99-999-99' and '999-99-999'. I need to change the input mask based on value length. 
If value length is 7 or smaller, the template must be '99-999-99'. If value length is bigger then 7, the temple must be '999-99-999'.

My code:

```
$("#carnum").keyup(()=>{
  var masks = ['99-999-99', '999-99-999'];
  var value = $('#carnum').val().replace(/-/g, '');
  value.length <= 7 ? -1 :  $('#carnum').mask(masks[1]);
})
$("#carnum").mask('99-999-99');
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alikchebotar/4m0uLxfs/4/).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before masking again to the same element it is a best practice to unmask it,
here is the sample code reference for changing mask dynamically or conditionally

```
var changeMask=0;
$("#carnum").keyup(()=>{
    var masks = ['99-999-99', '999-99-999'];
  var value = $('#carnum').val().replace(/-/g, '').replace(/_/g,''); 
  if(value.length==7){
  changeMask++;
  }
  if(changeMask>1&&value.length>=7) {
  $('#carnum').unmask(masks[0]); 
  $('#carnum').mask(masks[1]);
  var arrayValue=value.split("");
  $("#carnum").val("");
  for(var index=0;index<arrayValue.length;index++){
  $("#carnum").val(function(i, val) {
        return val + arrayValue[index];
    }).trigger('input');
  } 
  }
})
$("#carnum").mask('99-999-99');
```

**[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/77hhqnhu/)**